# Minimal requirements for Apache and MySQL for Symfony 2.8

Tags: mysql, apache, symfony, requirements, symfony-2.8

Symfony 2.8 [requires](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/requirements.html#required) PHP version to be **at least 5.3.9**, however nothing is mentioned regarding **Apache** and **MySQL** versions in the documentation. What are the minimal requirements for them?

Comment: Explain the downvote, maybe?

Comment: The Symfony framework itself has no database dependencies.  If you choose to use Doctrine 2 then it need to have a pdo driver installed.  So this is really a php question.  But seriously, if you plan on trying to use Symfony in a manner for which is not designed for and is completely unsupported then you need to buckle done and become a Symfony expert.

Comment: @Cerad I see. I just want to use symfony in a regular way, but with a legacy system.

Comment: Read carefully what your just wrote.  Can you spot the contradiction?

Comment: @Cerad Sorry, but I don't get you. What exactly makes you think, that I'm trying to use Symfony "in a manner for which is not designed for"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache and MySQL version are not *exactly* relevant there: Apache acts merely as a caller to PHP (in the most common `mod_php` stack), so it does not interact directly with Symfony. Plus Apache release cycles tend to be longer (2.2 from 2005 is still around).

Regarding MySQL, it concerns Doctrine exactly, especially the DBAL - *Database Abstraction Layer*. Doctrine [platforms documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/platforms.html) does not state much about it, we can infer it supports MySQL 5.0+.

Of course, the higher you can go is the better. PHP 5.3 is not supported anymore, nor PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5 (security bugs supports stopped last week). Apache 2.2 you need the very last "patch" version. MySQL dramatically improved in 5.5+.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I'd go with more up to date versions of everything, but I don't have that luxury. Btw, do you mean, that if apache is not updated, symfony won't run?

Comment: No - Apache does not directly interact with Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is mentionned in the documentation,then it means any version can be used most of the time.
I think you should simple use the latest version available in your distributions's repository.

Comment: I have to mess with legacy systems, thus I'm not free to choose what versions to work with

Comment: Then take the latest version that is compatible with your system.